# How can I use fragments and ActionBar in API10?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-support-library

I'm trying to implement Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views. I'm developing my Android application using 2.3.3.

Because Fragment and ActionBar ... are only supported in API 11 and above, I understood that I need to install the Support Library.

Which I did : [image]

Do I need to configure or install anything else to be able to work with the ActionBar for instance, which is still not working !!

Comment: you need to import the support library v7 which gives you access to the AppCompat library for the action bar. see this link http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Why not try ActionBarShelock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the action bar, you need to follow [the instructions to attach the v7 appcompat library project to your application project](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) (see "Adding libraries with resources").

For the fragments backport, your app probably already has `android-support-v4.jar` in `libs/`. If not, you will need to follow [the instructions to add that JAR to your application project](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) (see "Adding libraries without resources").

Comment: Thank you @tyczj, @Matan Dahan, @CommonsWare for the links. the explanations are very easy to follow. I'm trying to attach the V7 appcompat : When I finished creating the library project _android-support-v7-appcompat_ I got this error : `android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target android-16` I completed the steps anyway, and when I attached this library project to my actual one, I had another bunch of errors such as `Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar, Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies, No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar` ... Help

Comment: @ashabasa: "Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar"  -- your project, between its own `libs/` directory and the `libs/` directories of your attached Android library projects, has two copies of `android-support-v4.jar` that are not the same.